# MongoDB: Database too big to resync?

Tags: mongodb-3.2

we have a mongodb cluster which takes about 3.7TB on the filesystem. One of our secondary nodes died, so we replaced it and started the resync.

The resync was started on 12 Jul 2017 and took until yesterday (6 Aug 2017) I can see the index rebuilding and immediately after that, I got the magical message (there are dbs before the test one):

`[rsSync] initial sync cloning db: test
[rsSync] build index on: test.t1 properties: { v: 1, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "test.t1" }
[rsSync]         building index using bulk method
[rsSync] build index done.  scanned 0 total records. 0 secs
[rsSync] initial sync data copy, starting syncup
[rsSync] oplog sync 1 of 3
[ReplicationExecutor] syncing from: fr-mongo-c3-p3:27017
[rsBackgroundSync] we are too stale to use fr-mongo-c3-p3:27017 as a sync source
[ReplicationExecutor] syncing from: de-mongo-c3-b1:27017
[ReplicationExecutor] syncing from: de-mongo-c3-p1:27017
[ReplicationExecutor] syncing from: de-mongo-c3-p2:27017
[ReplicationExecutor] could not find member to sync from
[rsBackgroundSync] too stale to catch up -- entering maintenance mode
[rsBackgroundSync] our last optime : (term: 10, timestamp: Jul 12 05:29:26:14)
[rsBackgroundSync] oldest available is (term: 10, timestamp: Aug  3 06:24:29:9f0)`

Now what can I do with this? First thing that comes to mind is to increase the oplog size and repeat the process. Second thing that comes to mind is to take the backup data, copy them to this new node and if this process takes less then 4 days, I might be able to make it.

Any other ideas? Or is my assumption completely wrong? Thanks for answers!

(Mongo version is 3.2.10, OS is Ubuntu Trusty)

Comment: Have you considered [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/backup-with-filesystem-snapshots/)?

Comment: The backups I was talking about are made in similar way, so not exactly this, but close enough, thanks for the doc!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct in both cases! Actually, it would be best to do both!

First, increase the opLog size (at least 4x, 10x if you have space) and after that use backup method to copy all data to that node (lvm snapshot is best).

During that time what copy takes, your new opLog (what is this time much bigger) will collect all changes and still keep that starting point.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to restore the backup, so the syncing can finish, but when I copy the data and start mongo. It starts the "Initial sync" and drops all databases, which renders my backup useless, because it deleted it. Should I start the mongo differently or something? Thanks for help!

Comment: Depends on your backup method. If you want to "initialize" new node, backup MUST have opLog (and of course all databases, including local -db). LVM snapshot is fastest and best solution. If you can stop your PRIMARY node and take a copy of disk files (whole dbPath directory) to that "initializing" node, that will work too.

Comment: Our current backup method is to stop one of the secondary servers and copy all its files from /var/lib/mongo away to some location and start the server again

Comment: If you copy all dbPath files from stopped mongod instance and that instance belongs to the same replica set, it should work as "initial sync" without any problems... As long as file ownership is right when you start that "third" node. I have done many times new node that way, taking clone copy of one virtual machine (whole machine, all disks) and creating a new RS node from it. When this "drop all databases, except local" happened, what was a reason for rejecting existing data. That info should be in log file just before database drop.

Comment: This is the log: https://pastebin.com/eHzwTZdC

Comment: When you started that node, there was wiredTiger data files in the data directory `Detected data files in /var/lib/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine`, but those were NOT (at least fully) from other RS node because local database was missing `Did not find local voted for document at startup;  NoMatchingDocument: Did not find replica set lastVote document in local.replset.election` and `creating replication oplog of size: 51200MB...`